# Append a passed function parameter to $scope inside a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `ng-click="myMethod(parameter)"` inside a `<button>` element. I want to use this `parameter`, which in my case, is a string inside a controller so that I can do operations like `$scope.parameter.subProperties` on it. So in fact this parameter actually is an alias name for an existing $scope.object.

So my aim is to reuse this `myMethod()` in different places like `ng-click`'s in `<button>`'s and perform the same functionality on the corresponding `$scope` objects identified by the `parameter` name.

A mock code for finding the length of the `object1` inside the controller will be like:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.object1;
    $scope.object2;
    $scope.myMethod = function(arg){
        var length = $scope.arg.length;
    };
})
```

Here, the value passed as the argument could be one of the object names like this:

`<button ng-click="myMethod(object1)">Find Length</button>`

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the **bracket notation** when you have a dynamic key.

```
$scope.object1;

$scope.myMethod = function (arg) {
    var length = $scope[arg].length;
};
```

But you have to pass a string to the function.

```
<button ng-click="myMethod('object1')">Find Length</button>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! 
Accepting this as the most appropriate answer, as you pointed out the right syntax for the `ng-click` method call with the parameter inside the `<button>`.

Answer (score 2):

you should use **bracket notation** `[]` instead of **dot notation** `.` like `$scope[arg].length` to access **variable dynamically**

```
$scope.myMethod = function(arg){
   var length = $scope[arg].length;
};
```

and should use `parameter` as string so use `ng-click="myMethod('parameter')"` instead of `ng-click="myMethod(parameter)"`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following you, you want something like this:

```
    <div ng-controller="myController as foo">
       <button ng-click="foo.clickyclicky('barney')">Barney</button>
       <button ng-click="foo.clickyclicky('fred')">Fred</button>
    </div>
```

then your controller looks something like this:

```
    function myController() {
        var vm=this;
        vm.barney = {};
        vm.barney.wife = "Betty"
        vm.fred = {};
        vm.fred.wife = "Wilma" 

       function clickyclicky(who) {
           var hubby = vm[who]
           alert(hubby.wife) 
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, you've got me right. Appreciate the example!